# Umbraco - Media types not available and other media issues

Tags: umbraco

I'm using 4.11.4.

It has been upgraded from 4.9 I believe at some point, also IIS 7.5 on Windows 2008.

I have a number of problems with media.

I suspect they are all related but the upshot is that I can't create or upload media.
Symptoms are:

1.Right click on Media root and choose create - media item created (Media types file, folder, image present) - try to upload by clicking browse - operation never completes

2.Right click sub folder in Media - no media types available and cannot create media

[image]

[image]

3.Navigating to Media area usually would expect to see media item thumbnails on right hand side. This never happens and the progress icon just keeps spinning

[image]

Any ideas anybody?

Wing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things to check, first of all permissions and if no joy there suggest inspecting the page for script errors which can often lead you to more detail about the cause.

Comment: This is good advice and it did ultimately lead me to solving the problem which was in fact to do with a rewrite rule misbehaving so I'm going to add an answer to this but mark your answer up

Answer (score 0):

ProNotion's answer really helped solve this one.  He highlighted the importance of basic checks for permissions and script errors when troubleshooting in Umbraco but additionally I would say that if you are using rewrite rules anywhere try turning them off to see if this solves things. This ultimately worked for me. So when troubleshooting check:

- Permissions
- Script errors (Firebug)
- HTTP Traffic (Fiddler)
- Rewrite rules (try disabling) to see if this solves a problem)

Good luck

Wing